# I'm building an Angular application where I need to dynamically load different components based on user input

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive, angular-cli, angular-components

For example, let's say I have a dropdown menu with options A, B, and C. When the user selects an option, I want to load and display the corresponding component dynamically without reloading the entire page.

I've looked into **ngComponentOutlet** and **ComponentFactoryResolver**, but I'm still struggling to implement this functionality correctly. Can someone please guide me on how to dynamically load components in Angular based on user input?

Comment: You can use NgIf structural directive as one of possible and simple ways. https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description ngIf='A' -> show component A, etc.